# Is the YQL console page down for everyone (again)?

Tags: yql

Is anyone able to browse to the YQL console at https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console today?

It worked yesterday but now I only get a page that says "The requested page was not found" [like this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2l0l8ff2g5v67lv/Screenshot%202017-11-30%2011.31.29.png)

My existing scripts continue to work, and the sample console works at the [main YQL page](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

The same "page was not found" error also appears for anything in the ../yql/... directory like the [FAQ](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/faq) or [tutorial](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide).

Also - before anyone suggests this is off topic, please note that I am posting this here because Yahoo/Oath says YQL support questions can only be posted here with the yql tag, so I'm just doing the only thing that I can do about this.  ([source](https://developer.yahoo.com/support/yql))

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I got the same off topic treatment...I confirm this is where Yahoo is directing us to get answers

Comment: My application was down since last night (12/19).  YQL randomly failed due to OST_OAUTH_SIGNATURE_INVALID_ERROR.  That was the time I discovered YQL console has been down.  Also, the sample console is failing as well: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the console is down (since Nov. 30 at least), confirmed by YDN tweet:

*We are aware that the YQL Console is offline. We are investigating the issue. In the meantime, you can still continue to use YQL via our APIs. You can find the documentation here: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide*

source: https://twitter.com/ydn/status/936763870974173185